# Convert *.obj to *.fbx with Python FBX SDK

Tags: python, fbx

I try to find some documentation for Autodesk Python FBX SDK, but it seems that it is available only for C++ (http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_50489A8A_457C_4B54_80E1_5572A16F7F17_htm).

Does somebody know how convert *.obj to *.fbx with using Python FBX SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python FBX SDK lacks good documentation. Here is how you might get it to work.

```
import fbx

# Create an SDK manager                                                                                           
manager = fbx.FbxManager.Create()

# Create a scene
scene = fbx.FbxScene.Create(manager, "")

# Create an importer object                                                                                                  
importer = fbx.FbxImporter.Create(manager, "")

# Path to the .obj file
milfalcon = "samples/millenium-falcon/millenium-falcon.obj"

# Specify the path and name of the file to be imported                                                                            
importstat = importer.Initialize(milfalcon, -1)

importstat = importer.Import(scene)

# Create an exporter object                                                                                                  
exporter = fbx.FbxExporter.Create(manager, "")

save_path = "samples/millenium-falcon/millenium-falcon.fbx"

# Specify the path and name of the file to be imported                                                                            
exportstat = exporter.Initialize(save_path, -1)

exportstat = exporter.Export(scene)
```

Optionally, you can set export (and import) options with i.e.

```
ios = fbx.FbxIOSettings.Create(manager, fbx.IOSROOT)
manager.SetIOSettings(ios)

manager.GetIOSettings().SetBoolProp(fbx.EXP_FBX_SHAPE, False)
manager.GetIOSettings().SetBoolProp(fbx.EXP_FBX_GOBO, False)

exportstat = exporter.Initialize(save_path, -1, manager.GetIOSettings())
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw documentation. It contains only description of classes but not contains some simple tutorials or examples for someone who not familiar with FBX SDK.